Receiving an AuthException(message: AuthRetryableFetchError, statusCode: null) in my Flutter Web App when creating a user in Supabase
In my Web Administration Page made in Flutter that uses Supabase, I have a function/page to create a new user. However, I am encountering the error "AuthException(message: AuthRetryableFetchError, statusCode: null)" when trying to execute the insertion of the user. I have this function/data repository that inserts the data first in the auth.users table then to the public.profiles table for the user's details.
Here is the data repository code:
Future<String?> createUserAndProfile(
    String email,
    String password,
    String firstName,
    String middleName,
    String lastName,
    String accountType,
    String? empId,
    int? regionId,
    int? provinceId,
    int? municipalityId) async {
  final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
  try {
    final authResponse =
        await supabase.auth.signUp(email: email, password: password);

    if (authResponse.user == null) {
      return "Error in saving in database (auth)";
    }

    final user = authResponse.user!;

    final profileResponse = await supabase.from('profiles').insert({
      'id': user.id,
      'email': email,
      'firstname': firstName,
      'middlename': middleName,
      'lastname': lastName,
      'account_type': accountType,
      'employee_id': empId,
      'region_id': regionId,
      'province_id': provinceId,
      'municipality_id': municipalityId,
    });

    if (profileResponse.error != null) {
      return 'Error creating profile: ${profileResponse.error!.message}';
    } else {
      print('Profile created successfully!');
      return null;
    }
  } on AuthException catch (e) {
    return e.message; // Return the specific error message from AuthException
  } catch (e) {
    return 'An unexpected error occurred: ${e.toString()}';
  }
}


Here is the code snippet/function to where the function above is called:
Future<void> _handleSignUp() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      final email = _emailController.text.trim();
      final password = _passwordController.text.trim();
      final firstName = _firstNameController.text.trim();
      final middleName = _middleNameController.text.trim();
      final lastName = _lastNameController.text.trim();
      final empId = _employeeIdController.text.trim();

      /*
      print('Email: $email, password: $password');
      print('Name: $firstName $middleName $lastName');
      print('Employee Number: $empId');
      print(
          'Region: $_selectedRegionId, Province: $_selectedProvinceId, Municipality: $_selectedMunicipalityId');
      */

      final errorMessage = await createUserAndProfile(
          email,
          password,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          middleName,
          _accountType!,
          empId,
          _selectedRegionId,
          _selectedProvinceId,
          _selectedMunicipalityId);

      // Handle successful signup or potential errors
      // (e.g., show a success message or handle signup errors)
      _errorMessage.value = errorMessage;
    }
  }

I have tried to check if the values being passed to function are correct (the commented part above) and they are correct. When I tried to submit, the error message was "AuthRetryableFetchError".  The user is not being inserted in the auth.users table and consequently in the profiles table.  How can I debug what is wrong with my code, or did I miss some configuration for Supabase?
I tried using CoPilot and Gemini but both have generic answers that there may be a temporary network disruption or problem with the server. However, I am using a self-hosted Supabase using Docker and I had no trouble during the login process in my Web Application which uses the Supabase Auth.
Here is the schema of my profiles data:
CREATE TABLE profiles (
    id UUID REFERENCES auth.users NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP with time zone,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    middlename VARCHAR(30),
    account_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    employee_id VARCHAR(30),
    region_id INT REFERENCES regions(id),
    province_id INT REFERENCES provinces(id),
    municipality_id INT REFERENCES municipalities(id)
);

Update
It seems the error is due to the sending of the confirmation email. Here is the log I found:
"auth_event":{"action":"user_confirmation_requested","actor_id":"fff630ec-becc-4eea-bed1-d833cb25004a","actor_username":"test@example.com","actor_via_sso":false,"log_type":"user","traits":{"provider":"email"}},"component":"api","error":"Error sending confirmation email: dial tcp: lookup supabase-mail on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host","level":"error","method":"POST","msg":"500: Error sending confirmation mail","path":"/signup","referer":"http://localhost:57751/","remote_addr":"172.18.0.1","time":"2024-06-05T13:59:28Z","timestamp":"2024-06-05T13:59:24Z"

How can I create a user without needing a confirmation email? As mentioned this is a self hosted Supabase using Docker. I do not have my own SMTP server. I tried to use my Google account with an App password but nothing happens. Here is my snippet of the Supabase .env on email auth.
...
## Email auth
ENABLE_EMAIL_SIGNUP=true
ENABLE_EMAIL_AUTOCONFIRM=true
SMTP_ADMIN_EMAIL=<redacted>
SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
SMTP_PORT=587
SMTP_USER=<redacted>
SMTP_PASS=<redacted>
SMTP_SENDER_NAME=<redacted>
...

